# how can I identify that mousedragged event is stopped even though mouse is not released in java swing

Tags: java, swing

how can I identify that mousedragged event is stopped even though mouse is not released in java swing.
I need to implement a scenario in which when mouse is pressed and moved it has to behave as selection mode then if it waits at a particular location for some time then it behaves as drag drop mode.

Comment: Are you pausing within the component that you started dragging in?

Comment: if mouse isn't released after mouse down then dragged isn't stopped

Comment: Yes MadProgrammer, In my requirement If I pause at a location for some time then I need to change my mode.

Comment: So how can I identify that user has stopped moving mouse?

Comment: i think you can detect when mousemoving event stop for small time

Comment: Use a Swing `Timer` in the `mouseMoved` event, start/restart this `Timer`, set to a small delay (500 milliseconds).  Set it to non-repeating.  Once it triggers, you know the user stopped...

Comment: But timer concept creates one timer for every move. I mean if move mouse from once location to other location it creates timer for all the intermediate cooordinate.

Comment: Don't create it on every move. Create just one and restart on each move

Comment: Thanks to all of you.